# Making a fahrenheit to celsius converter and getting E0502

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

The goal is to make a program where from an input such as `56c` or `36f` it would understand which scale we are using and then convert accordingly. This is the current code:

```
use std::io;

fn main() {
    println!("Please input temp in format 35f/35c: ");
    let mut input = String::new();

    io::stdin()
        .read_line(&mut input)
        .expect("Failed to read line");

    let len = input.trim().len();
    let unit = &input[len - 1..];
    input.truncate(len - 1);
    if unit == "f" {
        let result = fahrenheit_to_c(input.parse::<i32>().unwrap());
        println!("{result}");
    } else if unit == "c" {
        let result = celsius_to_f(input.parse::<i32>().unwrap());
        println!("{result}");
    } else {
        println!("Please make the correct input!");
    }
}

fn fahrenheit_to_c(tempr: i32) -> i32 {
    (tempr - 32) * 5 / 9 as i32
}

fn celsius_to_f(tempr: i32) -> i32 {
    (tempr * 9 / 5) + 32 as i32
}
```

`Result` output worked when I tested it without the `if` statements, after I added `if` statements I started getting this

```
error[E0502]: cannot borrow `input` as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable
  --> src/main.rs:13:5
   |
12 |     let unit = &input[len - 1..];
   |                 ----- immutable borrow occurs here
13 |     input.truncate(len - 1);
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ mutable borrow occurs here
14 |     if unit == "f" {
   |        ---- immutable borrow later used here
```

I've tried having scale and temperature as different two different inputs to make the type conversion simplier but that's not what im aiming for here.

Comment: Have you read the error? You're trying to mutate a variable (`input.truncate()`) while having another reference to it (`&input[len - 1..]`). This is against the rules of the borrow checker.

Comment: Create a new slice that covers the rest of `input` and `parse` the slice, instead of mutating `input`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot modify `input` after you take a shared reference to it that you still use. `let unit = &input[len - 1..];` takes a shared reference to `input`.

Instead you can get two separated slices, `value` and `unit` with a simple `split_at`:

```rust
    let (value, unit) = input.split_at(len - 1);
```

now you can parse that `value` and use `unit` to decide how to handle it.

You'll still want to clean up `unit` because it still contains the `"\n"` the user put in.

Comment: thanks a lot i fixed it, as well added `let unit = unit.trim();` and now it works